# Binding xml document to a tree view dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Building on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954609/1317705) detailing how to render and bind a treeview to an xml document, I wonder if anyone could offer a way to make it more generic, such that it could accept any valid xml.

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="colorsTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="rootTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=FavoriteColors/Color}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource colorsTemplate}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=@FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" " />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=@LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" (Age: " />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=@Age, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text=")" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

For example, imagine that the load button, instead of statically loading People.xml, presented a file dialog, and the user could upload any xml file.
So this

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load("People.xml");
    people.Document = xmlDocument;
}
```

Would look more like like this

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
   bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

   if ( result == true ) {
       xmlDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
       people.Document = xmlDocument;
   }
}
```

How then could you define the bindings, which seem to rely on a knowledge of the property names from the xml being handled?

And how would you declare the HierarchicalDataTemplates, since the depth of the nodes is unknown prior to runtime?

My assumption is that the templates would have to be built in the code behind, but perhaps that is not correct.

Could anyone spin up an example of how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to change your XPath-Expression to child::node() and implement a datatrigger to distinguish between nodes and attributes.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="XmlDataBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
            <TextBlock x:Name="text"
                       Text="?" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding XPath="child::node()" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}"
                             Value="Text">
                    <Setter TargetName="text"
                            Property="Text"
                            Value="{Binding Path=Value}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}"
                             Value="Element">
                    <Setter TargetName="text"
                            Property="Text"
                            Value="{Binding Path=Name}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlDataProvider"></XmlDataProvider>

    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="treeView1"
                  Background="AliceBlue"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlDataProvider}, XPath=*}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind (substitute ViewModel to taste)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 

            var dataProvider = this.FindResource("xmlDataProvider") as XmlDataProvider;
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            // Testdocument
            doc.LoadXml(
                 @"<root>
                    <child1>text1<child11>text11</child11>
                    </child1>
                    <child2>text2<child21>text21</child21>
                        <child22>text22</child22>
                    </child2>
                  </root>");
            dataProvider.Document = doc;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very nice.  I have two follow up questions:  How would you then make the text editable (simply adding a TextBox control seems trickier than maybe it should be).  And two, how could you then handle attributes as well? That is what if it was written as `<child1 Name="text1">`

Comment: Editing is a whole new ballgame. My approach would be to parse the xml doc and create a heirarchy of NodeViewModels, with each NodeViewModel having AttributeViewModel and NodeVieWModel (Child nodeS) collections. Each of your viewmodels would have the XmlNode as their inner model and the ViewModel could mediate the writing of the values to the underlying Xml doc. That's really worthy of a whole new question though.

Comment: Cool, good advice there, I'm sure.  Any thoughts on adding attributes to the tree, or does that as well require a different approach?

Comment: Ahh, ok, so I changed the Binding from `child::node()` to `child::node()|@*`, and now it reads the attributes as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, btw.  Would you happen to be able to recommend a good  resource for wpf and xaml development. I'm brand new to it and I feel that documentation is a bit lacking.

Comment: Well I just learned something new with child::node()|@*! :) It's a good day. wrt resources, start with Dr Wpf and Josh Smith's MVVM pattern.